# Cannot connect to docker swarm service task

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm following a series of blog posts on Docker Swarm and trying to make an example in the last section of https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2016/09/11/docker-and-swarm-mode-part-2/ (Service Discovery and Load Balancing) work. The idea is to start 3 instances of a "whoami" service called `bar`, that simply reports it's host's hostname and 1 instance of a Nginx service called `foo`, from which to exec `/bin/bash` and fire requests to `bar`s via curl. However, my services exit immediately after start and won't let me execute any commands on them.

Given an existing Docker Swarm setup with 1 manager and 2 workers, on the manager node:

```
# docker service create --name foo --replicas 1 --network test nginx
194bw6mbgwyhmyl82zcxbyzat

# docker service create --name bar --replicas 3 --network test --publish 8000:8000 jwilder/whoami
alhz41p6usu7pbyesiiqh2hrd

# docker service ls
ID NAME REPLICAS IMAGE COMMAND
194bw6mbgwyh foo 0/1 nginx 
alhz41p6usu7 bar 0/3 jwilder/whoami

# docker service ps foo
ID NAME IMAGE NODE DESIRED STATE CURRENT STATE ERROR
5vlgohetx4l95hm2mcggd4r6a foo.1 nginx docker-swarm-1 Running Running 5 seconds ago

# docker service ps bar
ID NAME IMAGE NODE DESIRED STATE CURRENT STATE ERROR
f1w9dxlaqgjlscwkf6ocdrui9 bar.1 jwilder/whoami docker-swarm-2 Running Running 23 seconds ago 
7xg7p0rc8oerp0p6nvnm3l73i bar.2 jwilder/whoami docker-swarm-2 Running Running 24 seconds ago 
8m2ct4pcc8t263z1n4zmitn5y bar.3 jwilder/whoami docker-swarm-3 Running Running 25 seconds ago
```

And, as a result:

```
# docker exec -it 5vlgohetx4l95hm2mcggd4r6a /bin/bash
Error response from daemon: No such container: 5vlgohetx4l95hm2mcggd4r6a
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the title could be updated to "Cannot connect to docker swarm service task" or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id that command `docker service ps <service>` gives is not actually a container id, but a task id. To find out the container id, run `docker inspect --format="{{.Status.ContainerStatus.ContainerID}}" <task id>`. Alternatively, you can use just plain `docker ps` on the node where service task is running and find out the correct container by its name.